# Password management with pg_connect()?

Tags: postgresql, php5

I am new to using postgresql along with php, but something doesn't seem right here.  9/10 examples I've seen using sets the `password` parameter in plain text.

For example, here's one sample

`$con = pg_connect("host='localhost' dbname='testdb' user='postgres' password='password');`

**Is this common practice? Does this pose as a security risk? If so, Is there a better way to pass the `password` value?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common practice. Do ensure the server is secure and you can also enable postgres to listen on SSL so that the plain text password in transit is encrypted. You can also hash the password and send it to postgres. See the link below about auth methods.

See this for more information -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php

If you are very concerned about security, postgres allows more security via multiple ways. See here -- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html

Comment: You know, I was debating which SE site to post this.  The stackoverflow link is very helpul.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't use the plaintext password, because there is no challenge in this case, whatever token you used might as well be the password from an attacker's standpoint (even if it is a hash, it is all you need to authenticate).  If you are concerned about security, encapsulate the database connection in SSL.